# Expressions in ternary operators as functions

Tags: javascript

```
3>4?function1():function2()
```

Is it allowed to use functions in ternary operators?
I know you can use it for values, but for functions I am not certain.

Comment: I edited it so that it works for already defined functions, would that work?

Comment: Yes, you can define them and call them in ternary expressions like the below answer(s) show.

Comment: @learning2code see my second code snippet for already defined functions.

Answer (score 3):

You can. But like this

```
var func = 3 > 4 ? function(){
  console.log("3 is not greater than 4");
} : function(){
  console.log("3 IS greater than 4");    
};
```

Now `func` has a function reference that has been set conditionally. Calling it `func()` will result in `"3 IS greater than 4"`

However, if you already have created the function, then just reference would be enough. You should not call it. Just pass the reference.

```
var func = 3 > 4 ? func1 : func2;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do

```
var f = 3>4?function(){console.log("left")}:function(){console.log("right")}
```

or with your edit

```
var f = 3>4?function1:function2
```

then f will be the function ( not the result of the function )

```
f()
```

or if you want the value that those functions return

```
var v = 3>4?function1():function2()
```

`v` will now be whatever those functions returned

Answer (score 0):

This is valid JavaScript:

```
var b = true; 
var a = b == true ? function(){ return 1; } : function(){return 2; }
```

`a` is a `function` that depended upon the ternary condition, exactly as you'd (hopefully) expect.

If you're wanting `a` to instead be the return value of the function - call it.

```
var b = true; 
var a = b == true ? (function(){ return 1; }()) : (function(){return 2; }())
```